# Master Duels on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: steam

I trying to start Master Duels from Steam and i have tried with
LAUNCH OPTIONS PROTON_USE_WINE3D=1 %command% but it is not starting and i am using PROTON = 8.0 version?

Does anyone now how to start this game on Ubuntu?

Comment: Not sure which game you're talking about exactly, but with that kind of question you are usually better off checking https://www.protondb.com/